# What is the relation between the square root of the sum of squares and the sum of the absolute values?

Tags: summation, absolute-value, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I want to prove that $\sqrt{\sum a_{i}^{2}} \geq \sum \left | a_{i} \right |$, is it possible ?

Comment: Consider the comparison $\sqrt a+\sqrt b,\sqrt{a+b}$.

Comment: The inequality should be the other way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $(\sum |a_i|) ^2 \geq \sum a_i^2$. Now take square roots.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, but I'm still away from my original purpose which is to show that $\left | a_{i,i} \right | \geq \sum_{j \neq i} \left | a_{i,j} \right |$ knowing that $\left | a_{i,i} \right |^{2} \geq \sum_{j \neq i} \left | a_{i,j} \right |^{2}$, is there another method to do it ?